# NuxtJS no errors are display in console or browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm very new to nuxt and I have a basic question about the error handling in development mode. My application has a basic component that contains an error. Normally I except a detailed error message in my browser console or the application console. But I only get this:

[image]

From where can I get a detailed error message?

Comment: https://dev.to/nuxt/nuxtjs-from-terminal-to-browser-35bc

Comment: No errors displayed in the browser or node console :(

Comment: https://github.com/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/issues/301

maybe a linter rule?